# I'm not getting the desired output, for this simple program in C++ , please help me in finding my mistakes

Tags: c++

**Ques:**

*A student will not be allowed to sit in exam if his/her attendence is less than 75%. Take following input from user Number of classes held Number of classes attended. And print percentage of class attended Is student is allowed to sit in exam or not.*

**MY_solution :**

```
int main()
{
   int nca;
   int nch;
   int pattend;
   cout << "Enter no. of classes held : " << endl;
   cinnch;
   cout << "Enter no. of classes attended : " << endl;
   cinnca;
   pattend = (nca / nch * 100);
   cout << "Percentage attendence : " << pattend << endl;
   if (pattend = 75) {
       cout << "Allowed to Give EXAMS :) " << endl;
   }
   else {
       cout << "NOT ALLOWED! Wasted" << endl;
   }
}
```

**My_output:**

**Enter no. of classes held :  100

Enter no. of classes attended :  50

Percentage attendence : 0

NOT ALLOWED! Wasted**

I'm not getting percentage attendance correct .

Comment: Probably you should use `double` variables instead of `int`.

Comment: Try `pattend=100.0 * nca/nch;` here: [https://ideone.com/NifP3l](https://ideone.com/NifP3l)

Comment: Please put a bit of effort into useful variable names. `nca`, `nch`, `pattend`, `cinnch`, and `cinnca` are completely unclear. Using good variable names is critical, _especially_ when expecting somebody else to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing two integers will give an integer result, so in your case 50/100 = 0.

If you want a floating point result, you need to change your variable types to float or double.